# Python: get or set value in dictionary by pointer of key

Tags: python, pointers, dictionary, reference

How can I set a value in dictionary by reference?

```
def set(point):
    point=0

dic={'pointer':22}
set(dic['pointer'])

print dic   # {'pointer': 0}
```

I must send one argument.

Comment: why do you have to do this? It's not a good idea.

Comment: Be clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: "why do you have to do this? It's not a good idea" For example you want to traverse some hierarchical structure like JSON with path notation. Haveing such pointing/reference mechanism will make real life better.

Answer (score 14):

Don't create a function named `set`, as you'll override the builtin of the same name.

Assuming you want to set value in a `dict`, which is not totally clear from your question, you could just use assignment:

```
dic={'pointer':22}
dic['pointer'] = 0

print dic   # {'pointer': 0}
```

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you want to do?

```
>>> dic = {'pointer':22}
>>> dic['pointer'] = 0
>>> print dic
{'pointer':0}
```

It's unclear from your question.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a slightly different meaning from your question than others, how do I set a value by reference:

```
def setit(point, adic): 
    adic[point] = 0

dic={'pointer':22} 
setit('pointer',dic) 

print dic   # {'pointer': 0}
```

In your version, the call to the set function passing `set(dic['pointer'])` will just pass the value.

Python does not have a pointer type like, say, C.  Variables are references, so pointers are not required.

Answer (score 1):

While python doesn't really have pointer objects like you seem to be looking for, mutable objects can be modified as you might want (so a list, dict, that kind of thing. Not an int or a str). And that is the key; they can be modified, not set within a function like that. If you try to set the value with an `=`, it only changes the variable within `setit`'s local scope. If you access the variable and modify it, then the actual object within the dictionary will remain modified.

```
def setit(val):
    val.pop() 
    val.append(0)
dic = {'pointer':['22']}
setit(dic['pointer'])
print dic # {'pointer':[0]}
```